# How put a Confirmation in Hyperlink DataGridView

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I want is to have a confirmation before deleting a records in my datagridview. Please check my codes.. Thanks.

here's my asp.net code:

```
<ItemTemplate><asp:HyperLink ID="hlnk_Delete" runat="server" style="width:100px; margin-left:50px; margin-right:100px"
    NavigateUrl='<%# "Components/DeleteBook.aspx?SKU=" + Utility.SKUMask(Eval("lbhc_lb_sku").ToString()) %>'>Delete</asp:HyperLink></ItemTemplate>
```

Sqldatasource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sds_PublishedBookListings" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:learningisfunConnectionString %>"

SelectCommand="SELECT dbo.lif_bookshascategory.lbhc_lc_id,dbo.lif_books.lb_sku, dbo.lif_bookshascategory.lbhc_lb_sku, dbo.lif_category.lc_category, dbo.lif_books.lb_title, &#13;&#10;                      dbo.lif_bookshascategory.lbhc_level&#13;&#10;FROM         dbo.lif_bookshascategory INNER JOIN&#13;&#10;                      dbo.lif_category ON dbo.lif_bookshascategory.lbhc_lc_id = dbo.lif_category.lc_id INNER JOIN&#13;&#10;                      dbo.lif_books ON dbo.lif_bookshascategory.lbhc_lb_sku = dbo.lif_books.lb_sku&#13;&#10;WHERE     (dbo.lif_books.lb_status = 'publish') and lbhc_level = 1&#13;&#10;" 

DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM lif_books FROM lif_books INNER JOIN lif_bookshascategory ON lif_books.lb_sku = lif_bookshascategory.lbhc_lb_sku WHERE (lif_books.lb_sku = @lbhc_lb_sku) OR (lif_bookshascategory.lbhc_lb_sku = @lbhc_lb_sku)">
<DeleteParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="lb_sku" Type="String" />
</DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this your hyperlink

```
onclick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ?');"

<ItemTemplate><asp:HyperLink ID="hlnk_Delete" onclick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ?');" runat="server" style="width:100px; margin-left:50px; margin-right:100px"
NavigateUrl='<%# "Components/DeleteBook.aspx?SKU=" + Utility.SKUMask(Eval("lbhc_lb_sku").ToString()) %>'>Delete</asp:HyperLink></ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [JavaScript Confirm DialogBox](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/confirm.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Add to you Hyperlink OnclientClick="confirm('are you sure?'); return false"

Comment: there is on onClientClick property exist of hyperlink.